# Setting up maven Project

Tags: maven, config

I am trying to setup a maven project via eclipse,but it is throwing following error.

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact 
     descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from/
     to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection refused: connect
    - CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact 
     descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from https://
     repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could 
     not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection refused: connect
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)
    - Connection refused: connect
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"; xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:schemaLocation="maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">; <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> <groupId>MavenRep</groupId> <artifactId>om.spring.learnings</artifactId> <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> <name>SampleSpringBoot</name> </project>
```

Following is my settings.xml

settings.xml:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host> myhostname</host>
      <port>9080</port>
      <username>xxx</username>
      <password>xxxx</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>80</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

Comment: Please Show your pom.xml

Comment: Please add it o your quetion using the edit dunction not as comment

Comment: You are behind a Proxy?

Comment: Yes...Can i post the settings.xml also

Comment: Yes but be sure that you mask your Password. But i am not sure if it helps, because i do not know your infrastructure

Comment: But you can try using `mvn -X compile` to get debug informations

Comment: I noticed you have "om.spring.learnings" for `artifactId` - did you mean to use "com.spring.learnings" here instead?

Comment: Yes Jonathan.I am trying to learn spring boot with maven

Comment: Ok.............@Jens

Comment: I have used mvn -X compile @Jens

Comment: you must have a typo maybe mvn two times in the command line

Comment: please run `mvn -X compile` on your command line

Comment: Why do you have a semicolon after the `<project>` tag? The xml of pom.xml is not valid.